Considerations for Output Capacitance in LDO and SMPS Circuits
In LDO or SMPS circuits, the maximum capacitive load is generally specified. Is the capacitance at the output of the LDO or SMPS circuit used after the SMPS LDO output also included in the output capacitance of the main SMPS or LDO?
If there are additional capacitances downstream from the LDO or SMPS output, such as capacitors at various stages of a power distribution network, are nthey  typically included in the specified maximum capacitive load of the LDO or SMPS itself?
For easier understanding, should Capacitors C2 and C3 be included in the output capacitance load of Smps1?


I suspect that a general answer may not be as useful as getting an answer to a specific scenario where the devices are defined and have data sheets.

the maximum capacitive load is generally specified Indeed, but sometimes the specified maximum is infinity. The legacy 3-pin regulators 78xx, 79xx, and LM338 have such infinite specifications, for example. In other cases, the maximum capacitance and ESR are related, and in many cases with just a couple ohms of ESR the maximum spec becomes infinite.

Is it similar to the situation where the resistor placed at the output of opamps isolates it from the capacitive load?


Is the capacitance at the output of the LDO or SMPS circuit used after the SMPS LDO output also included in the output capacitance of the main SMPS or LDO?

The total capacitance seen by the output.
Say you have an output electrolytic across SMPS1's output (C1). If SMPS2 and SMPS3 have their own input capacitors* then they are going to be added so the total capacitance seen by SMPS1 output will be higher.

For easier understanding, should Capacitors C2 and C3 be included in the output capacitance load of Smps1?

The output capacitance of SMPS2 and SMPS3 normally shouldn't reflect to the input.
* Any SMPS other than a PFC regulator can be considered as capacitive load, hence the maximum capacitive load rating for SMPSs i.e. an SMPS output can be used as input for multiple SMPSs.
